# Through a SQL table show the data stored in a textbox using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Actualizarperfil(registro m)
    {
        masterEntities db = new masterEntities();
     
        ViewBag.Lista = db.registro.Where(x => x.usuario == m.usuario).ToList();
        return View();
    }
```

So I send it to call in my textbox with value:

```
    <div class="form-group">
       <label for="Nombre" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Nombre</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <input type="text"
                 name="nombre"
                 placeholder="Nombre"
               class="form-control" required autofocus value="@Html.DropDownList("MiLista", new SelectList(ViewBag.Lista, "Nombre", "Nombre"))">
    </div>
</div>
```

but my error is that it does not show me anything in the textbox:

[image: error]

Where will I be wrong or any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<input type="text"
           name="nombre"
           placeholder="Nombre"
           class="form-control" required autofocus value="@Html.DropDownList("MiLista", new SelectList(ViewBag.Lista, "Nombre", "Nombre"))">
```

Could you not simply just have:

```
@Html.DropDownList("MiLista", new SelectList(ViewBag.Lista, "Nombre", "Nombre", "Nombre"), new { @class="form-control"})
```

From what I can see, currently you are specifying a textbook but wanting it tone a dropdown list. So you'd either have to use a `<select>` tag OR an alternative such as below.

Note: You could also use `DropDownListFor` as well

Comment: if I want to send to print through a select several fields that are stored in my table to some textbox